# How to change device language without user interference automatic through coding

Tags: javascript, android

I want to change the device language without any user interaction programmatically. I have tried [this method](http://bin-liu.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-change-system-locale-calling.html).
I am getting the following error.

Error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method updateConfiguration(Landroid/content/res/Configuration;)
    V in class Landroid/app/IActivityManager; 
    or its super classes (declaration of 'android.app.IActivityManager' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
```

Is there any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found answer for that we need to add line in menifest file   " uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" and allow permission to mobile by using adb command "adb grant mypackage android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" and and i use reflection class method as i mention link above in my question its working